# Vue cli build production change opacity in css

Tags: css, vue.js, build, vuejs2

When I build my vue project, it changes opacity from 50% to 1%.

In development it doesn't have this problem but in production it changes style.

development (npm run serve):
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1BdV.png)

```css
.VueCarousel-dot-container button.VueCarousel-dot {
    background-color: #7390a7 !important;
    opacity: 60%;
}
```

production (npm run build):
When I build and upload it:

```css
.VueCarousel-dot-container button.VueCarousel-dot {
    background-color: #7390a7!important;
    opacity: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try replacing the `opacity: 60%;` with `opacity: 0.6;` which is the equivalent, but there might be a problem with CSS minification/transpilation in your build script.
Also, when you set the opacity in percentage, only Firefox (70+) and Chrome (78+) can understand it, other browser support just values which are in range from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Comment: Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/issues/118), please vote for reopen!